# How to upload file in flask restful swagger

Tags: python, rest, swagger, flask-restful

I want to upload a json file in flask restful swagger api,this is my parameter

```
  parameters=[
      {
            "name": "filename",
            "description": "json file upload ",
            "required": True,
            "allowMultiple": False,
            "dataType": "file",
            "paramType": "body"
        }
```

I use

> parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
>
> parser.add_argument('filename', type=str, location='args')
>
> args = parser.parse_args()
>
> print(args.filename)

to get the uploaded file name,I print it but it's None.

How can I upload a file in flask restful swagger api?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but...

You need to edit your endpoint definition in the `swagger.yaml` API specification file, e.g like this:

```
paths:
  '/your/api/upload':
    post:
      summary: Upload a file.
      operationId: postFile
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file # change it to your parameter name
          required: true
          type: file
          description: Stream to write to filesystem
        # other optional form parameters, e.g. ...
        - in: formData
          name: offset
          type: integer
          description: Bytes to skip at the beginning of the file
```

Afterwards, you can generate the Python controller automatically e.g. using the [Swagger Editor](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-editor/)'s builtin function.

Ref: [Swagger 2.0 docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/)

Answer (score -1):

I have solve this problem,to write here ：

change

parser.add_argument('filename', type=str, location='args')

to

parser.add_argument('filename', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')

but you need import werkzeug first

then you can user the method of werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage class

can use it from http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/

file = args.filename

filename = file.filename   # upload file name

file.save(savePaths) #you can save file to the path that you want to save
                     #but remember savePaths includes the file's filename

Or you can use the method below to save file:

lines = file.read()    #bytes class

f = open(filename,"wb")   #new a file and give it the filename

f.write(lines)     #write bytes

f.close()

and now:
parameters=[
            {
                "name": "filename",
                "description": "dd",
                "required": True,
                "allowMultiple": False,
                "dataType": 'file',
                "paramType": "body"
            }
        ]